# `git branch` output empty without `sudo` on macOS

Tags: git, macos, zsh

I am having an issue where the output of `git branch` is empty without `sudo`. This applies to *any* git repo (at least all that I have tested), including new ones. I have tested this in `zsh`, `bash3` and `bash5`, both with the bundled version of `git` and the Homebrew version. Interestingly, `git checkout` autocomplete (using git plugin of oh-my-zsh) still works as expected, as well as `git branch --show-current`.

I suspect a UNIX permission problem, but I cannot find any file or directory in `.git/` that does not have `-r--r--r--` permissions or higher, or that are not owned by current user.

Comment: Try `git --no-pager branch`

Comment: That worked? What..?

Comment: Seems like a broken pager. You need to investigate what's going on: what is your current pager and its configuration.

Comment: Problem was indeed my pager, see my own answer below. Thanks! :D

Comment: What is a pager (is it like less?) and how do I find out if that's the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: `less` is an example of a pager, yes. It is a program that takes an input and buffers it to the screen. If you have the same problem as me, then running the command in question with `--no-pager` as @phd suggest should work. To fix you must edit the git config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was a bad `.gitconfig`. I had the pager set to `LESSCHARSET="UFT-8 less -RF`. `-F` causes the pager to terminate when it hits `EOF` and `less` does not keep output after termination, causing the apparent empty output.

Comment: Add the `-X` option to your `less` command option set, so as to avoid using the init/deinit sequences; or switch to a Terminal emulator that doesn't use the <censored> Alternate Screen. See https://superuser.com/questions/134598/how-can-you-turn-off-alternate-screen-in-osxs-terminal-app (not the answer, just the question and its links).