# Git branch not displaying any results

Tags: python-3.x, git

When I run `git branch -a` in a folder with a .git directory, NOTHING is returned. I have been working in this directory for a few months and `git branch` used to return all local and remote branches.

My PyCharm IDE can still see all of the branches just fine.

I have searched for answers throughout SO and other sites to no avail.

Comment: Do you perhaps not have any local branches? What does `git branch -a` show?

Comment: What does `ls .git/refs/heads` show?

Comment: What is your pager set to? (Run `git var pager`.) Does `git --no-pager branch` work?

Comment: You said ".git file". Did you mean ".git directory"? (I assume yes if it's the "same" directory you've been using, and if you can see the branches from another Git client looking at the same place.)

Comment: `git branch -a` returns NOTHING. 
I did mean git directory.

Comment: `git var pager`: usage: git var (-l | <variable>)

Comment: `ls .git/refs/heads`: 09/07/2021  03:50 PM    <DIR>          .
09/07/2021  03:50 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/24/2021  03:23 PM                41 cleanup
09/07/2021  03:50 PM                41 develop
08/12/2021  11:37 AM                41 main
09/02/2021  04:24 PM                41 release
               4 File(s)            164 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  372,438,401,024 bytes free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `git branch` used to return all local and remote repositories.

Only [`git branch -a`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--a) would return all local and remote tracking *branches* (branches, not "repositories").

Check first if, as commented, this is [a pager issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66871290/6309). Change shell (if you are on Windows, switch between CMD, Powershell or bash, to see if the issue persists)

> `git --no-pager branch` does work!
> How do I fix git branch based on this info?

As [noted in `git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pagerltcmdgt):

> To disable pagination for all commands, set `core.pager` or `GIT_PAGER` to `cat`.
>
> ```
> git config core.pager cat
> ```

But for disabling it only for git branch, you have various options as described in the similar question  "[How do I prevent '`git diff`' from using a pager?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2183900/6309)"

An alias for `git -P branch` would be one of them. (`-P` is `--no-pager`)

Comment: `git --no-pager branch` does work! How do I fix git branch based on this info? The linked pager issue SO does not sufficiently describe how to fix the problem.

Comment: @krkaufma I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: `git config core.pager cat` in the command line fixed the issue